# Best container to use for searching and sorting

Tags: c++, stl

I have a pure virtual class for storing log data. This class has two pieces of information: `std::string id` (unique) and `int64_t time` (duplicates allowed) with `getId()` and `getTime()` functions. As the log entries are created, they will go into a container and on application termination, the log messages are written to file.

As the program continues, I may want to update a log entry, so I will need to search for `id` to find the correct entry to update. On shutdown, I want the results to be logged in `time` order.

I thought of storing the objects in a `std::map` where the `id` as the key, the object as the value for easy searching and updating. On shutdown, create a `std::multimap` or `std::vector` to do the sort before writing. Is this the best approach? Or is there a better object that can support both needs?

Comment: Are you sure id should be a string? Sounds very error prone. Integers would probably make better keys for log ids.

Comment: I am using the system's `uuid` functions to generate them as they **must** be different, even when compared to logs from other runs.

Comment: How many entries are you going to have?  How frequently will you be adding entries vs. updating entries?

Comment: Anywhere from 0 to hundreds of thousands of additions depending on setup and need. Generally, no more than 25% of the entries will ever be updated.

Comment: Why are you updating a log entry?

Comment: Does it matter? It isn't a debug log, it is a processing log. As processing continues, the information may become more refined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're only going to need the entries sorted on time once, when the program exits, I think your proposed solution is good.

If you were going to need the entries sorted on both time and id several times `boost::multi_index` would be a good candidate.

Comment: +1 I like `multi_index`, hadn't heard of it before. I need to spend time investigating boost.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Containers]
<sub>(source: [adrinael.net](http://adrinael.net/containerchoice))</sub>

(original source: [Liam Devine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170427104755/http://www.liamdevine.co.uk:80/code/containers.php))

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to have a pair of maps. Keep track of both `map<string, entry*>` and `map<integer, entry*>`.

On update, then, you would only need to search by id, and edit the pointed object. When pulling out all entries from the time map, you'd have the modified entries. This assumes that id and time values for entries are immutable.

Comment: Yes, that would work, and is what I alluded to in my question. But there is a lot of overhead maintaining two maps, which I was hoping to eliminate. Also, the second map would have to be a `multimap`.

Comment: If you aren't guaranteed to need to output the entries i'd revert to sort on display.

Comment: @steveo225 Since you're only going to need to sort on time once, I think your proposed solution (especially using vector) is perfect

Answer (score 1):

**If** the entries are generated in order of their `time` values **and** the `time` is not changed when you do the update, than you can simply:

- Add entries to `std::vector<entry*>` (or `std::list<entry*>`) as they are generated.
- And also add them to `std::map<std::string, entry*>` (or `std::unordered_map<std::string, entry*>`).

The `map` allows for fast searching during updates. When the time comes to dump the entries to file, simply traverse the `std::vector` in-order.

*(There are variations that could save you some heap allocations, such as: `std::vector<entry>` and `std::map<std::string, std::vector<entry>::size_type>`, where the `size_type` is the index of the vector element.)*

If, however, you need to update the `time` as well, I don't think you'll be able to avoid using `std::multimap` instead of the `std::vector`.

**-- EDIT ---**

OK, so you don't have in-order `time`, how about this:

Maintain just one `map<string, entry>` and when the time comes to dump it into file, generate a `vector< map<string, entry>::const_iterator >` from it and `std::sort` it on `time` (use the *comparer* parameter of `std::sort`).

Considerations:

- You can also just use `vector<entry*>` for sorting - the idea is that you
  are not allocating any new entries, you are just "pointing" to
  entries in the `map`.
- Also note that you can can pre-reserve `vector`
  to match the `map.size()`, so vector re-allocations are avoided.
- If you don't need to actually sort by entry IDs, consider using `unordered_map` (instead of just plain `map`) for performance.

This is cheaper overall than maintaining the second `map`, but adds a delay before dumping to file. Depending on your performance requirements, this may or may not be the optimal solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not generated in order of `time`. `time` is a timestamp that is generated from processing the data. Thanks for the answer though, there are some good insights.

Comment: @steveo225 I just realized you may have a race condition in your program (presuming you are only appending to file): Let's say you have dumped entries into the file and the next entry is generated. Since entries are not generated in their temporal order, there is no guarantee the new entry will not be older than the last entry within file. No matter how you sort the new set of entries, there is a potential that it will "overlap" the old set that is already in the file.

Comment: The entries are all stored in memory until application termination, then all written at once. There will only be a single file write.

Answer (score 0):

`stl::map` will do fine. And if I remember right, `std::map` is implemented with binary trees under the hood, so it should already be sorted, as long as you overload the `operator<` operator. So to have the map sorted by the timestamp, override `operator<` to compare the timestamps.

Comment: Yes, that is true, and that's why I suggested using them for storing the `id` to make searching easier. However, when I write them, I want them written sorted on `time`, thus I would need to transfer them to another object first, and that is the overhead I am trying to eliminate.

Comment: `map` only utilizes `operator<`, not `operator==` (a correct `operator<` implementation allows `map` to test equality using `!(a < b || b < a)`).

Comment: The map is already sorted on `id` and this is what needs to be fast since this is the lookup that will be done most often. The container only needs to be sorted on `time` once, at program exit.

Comment: @James that's what I thought, but I couldn't remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector for store entries. On creation you can assign to UID every entry, but you can use entry HANDLE to modify item. HANDLE can be entry pointer or array index. In this case you will get O(1) complexity on entry access.
Also you don't need sorting before log output. array already sorted in order of entry creation.
Better solution to create static array of entry structures with reasonable size. This will eliminate dynamic memory use.

Edit: Before output you can sort this array to get entries in order of time

Comment: And where do you store tgw handles?

Comment: In same place where you store UUID. You don't need to store handles in array